# Scalatest: Iterable should not contain any of the following set?

Tags: scalatest

Currently in ScalaTest,  we can do

```
Set(1,2,3,4) should not contain (5)
Set(1,2,3,4) should not contain (6)
```

What would be good ScalaTest style to do:

Set(1,2,3,4) should not contain any of Set(5,6)

Currently, I can only think of

```
Set(1,2,3,4) & Set(5,6) should be ('empty)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Scalatest 1.x you can only use something like:

> Set(1,2,3,4) should not (contain (5) or contain(6))

or

> set2.foreach(set1 should not contain _)

but there's no elegant way to express that having two sets, they should not intersect.
In Scalatest 2.0 (which is in RC1 state at the moment) you can tweak above version a bit as:

> Set(1,2,3,4) should contain noneOf (5, 6)

but still you cannot use a value of type Set and you have to give the elements directly.